# People API 'copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup' is returning a 404 error

Tags: google-people-api

I am trying to automate the movement of "hidden"/"Other Contacts" into the "My Contacts" group/membership via the People API, but I'm getting a 404 not found error.

My simplified code looks like the following:

```
function copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup() {

    var otherContactsList = People.OtherContacts.list({
        pageSize:10,
        readMask: 'emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers',
    });

    var otherContacts = otherContactsList.otherContacts;

    for(var oC in otherContacts) {
        var resourceName    = otherContacts[oC].resourceName;
        People.OtherContacts.copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup(resourceName, {"copyMask": "emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers"});
    };
}
```

```
var resourceName    = "otherContacts/c1528566360341757340";
```

I have successfully used the API Explorer with the above resourceName.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @ale13

Google responded that the JSON needs to be paced before the resourceName.

Corrrected Line of Code

People.OtherContacts.copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup({"copyMask": "emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers"}, resourceName);

Answer (score 0):

#### It looks like what you are experiencing might in fact be a bug.

Taking this into account, I have submitted a report on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189353112).

I suggest you star the issue and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it as any updates will be posted there.